# Trying to figure out what is causing kernel panic, problem report inside

Tags: macos, kernel-panic

Trying to figure this out since it is driving me insane. I looked up my third party kexts and only thing is little snitch, thats not even in this report so it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Can this be a problem with my boot drive? BootROM MP61.0120.B00, I'm not sure how to update since the original apple drive is no longer installed.

Any help would be appreciated. Not too sure on how to read this thing, is it saying "`com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[26E33FBA-73DC-3D8A-AA62-16A25FA97C8A]@0xffffff7f9af92000->0xffffff7f9afd0fff`" is the source of the issue?

https://pastebin.com/GUJBzG7a

thank you

Comment: last loaded kext at 80904036050366: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3 (addr 0xffffff7f9bc22000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 80991183810953: com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme  3 (addr 0xffffff7f9bc22000, size 32768)

Comment: Disable any Open at Log in and restart

Comment: went ahead and removed login items and restarted. This issue happens randomly so I'm not sure if its fixed until it happens again.

Comment: OK, lets wait and see

Comment: I just ran EtreCheck, Mac tool and it is saying the problem is from "3rd party kernel extensions: 
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch 5204

Comment: I don't get it, I was sure little snitch wasn't an issue but maybe. Ill contact their support and see what they say about this panic

Comment: well that's is the only 3D party app you have running